# cuda on integrated gpu + external device

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cuda, gpgpu

I have a dell desktop pc which has an integrated gpu.
If I add one more gpu over PCIe will I be able to run cuda? Probably yes.
The integrated gpu has its own driver (i915) and I am not sure what will happen with nvidia driver (for the second gpu) alongside.
Is there a special procedure, something to take into account?

edit: forgot to mention that OS is Ubuntu 11.10. sorry

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:
finally there is a problem. I just put the video card gtx 460. I want to have the display on integrated card so as to use the "good" card dedicated to computing. but if i dont plug the monitor cable to gtx I get the following message

> System halted! Attention: Unsupported Video Configuration Detected
>
> Action is Required
>
> This computer has an add-in graphics card, but the monitor is plugged
>   into the integrated video connector. To attach the monitor cable to
>   the add-in graphics card:
>
> 1. Shut down the computer
> 2. Plug the monitor cable into the add-in graphics card connector. This may require a video adapter or video adapter cable. (provided
>      with the system)
> 3. Turn on the computer.
>
> This message should not appear after completing these steps. For more
>   information or help, please refer to the system documentation.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

CUDA only supports NVidia GPUs so it won't even see the embedded intel one.

The CUDA startup functions also return the type and capabilities of all the CUDA devices found so you can pick which device to run a task on.

ps. You might want to manually set the app to 'use enhanced/performance graphics' in windows explorer->properties - we have had issues in laptops with Intel+Nvidia optima systems where the app doesn't see the Nvidia GPU by default for some reason